# How to get position of an item in ListView in JavaFX?

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

If I create a ListView in JavaFX like this:

```
ObservableList<String> elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList("John", "Doe");
ListView<String> lView = new ListView<String>(elements);
```

What I want to do is draw a line starting from the end of a row in the ListView, say from "John"

To do this, I need the location(x,y) of the row "John". Is it possible to get the location?

**Update**

This is a sample interface that I got using Swing and Piccolo2D. However, using that library is painful. I am wondering if I can do the same in JavaFX

[image]

Comment: You may need to extend ListView<String> and customize it so that a certain position has a line at that GUI.  I don't see any easy way to get the position without using a mouse-related event...

Comment: Hi Ankit. At what moment do you want to perform this operation? When the user click on the list item?

Comment: Do you want to draw a line for each row? Picture illustration will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it may not be as straight forward as you hoped. In order to determine the layout coordinates for a particular `Cell` within a `ListView` (or `TableView/TreeView`) you need to have access to that particular `Cell` object. The best way (and maybe only way in JavaFX 2.2) is to provide the container with a custom `Cell` and `CellFactory` that exposes each `Cell`. How you expose the `Cell` depends on what your triggers are for drawing the line.

Bases on your illustration, you'll need access to each cell once the `ListView`s are populated. You can do this with a `List<ListCell<String>>` field in the `CellFactory`. I'll mention one caveat here about `ListCell`s. The `ListViewSkin` will reuse `Cell`s whenever possible. That means that if you are going to try to populate and connect a list that ends up scrolling, then keeping your lines in the right place will be much more difficult. I'd recommend trying to ensure that all your list items fit on screen.

Below is an example with some notes in the comments. Take note that getting the correct coordinates for drawing your `Line` will probably require calculating the offset of your SceneGraph which I didn't do in this example.

```
package listviewcellposition;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewCellPosition extends Application {

    // CustomCellFactory for creating CustomCells
    public class CustomCellFactory implements
            Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> {

        List<ListCell<String>> allCells = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(final ListView<String> p) {
            final CustomCell cell = new CustomCell();
            allCells.add(cell);
            return cell;
        }

        public List<ListCell<String>> getAllCells() {
            return allCells;
        }
    }

    // CustomCell is where the exposure occurs. Here, it's based on the
    // Cell being selected in the ListView. You could choose a different
    // trigger here but you'll need to explore.
    public class CustomCell extends ListCell<String> {
        // General display stuff
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(item == null ? "" : item);
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // This pane will contain the lines after they are created.
        // I set it into an AnchorPane to avoid having to deal with 
        // resizing.
        Pane linePane = new Pane();
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        pane.setPrefSize(100, 250);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(linePane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(linePane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(linePane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(linePane, 0.0);
        pane.getChildren().add(linePane);

        ListView<String> lView = new ListView<>();
        lView.setPrefSize(100, 250);
        CustomCellFactory lCellFactory = new CustomCellFactory();
        lView.setCellFactory(lCellFactory);

        ListView<String> rView = new ListView<>();
        rView.setPrefSize(100, 250);
        CustomCellFactory rCellFactory = new CustomCellFactory();
        rView.setCellFactory(rCellFactory);

        lView.getItems().addAll("Bill", "Doctor", "Steve", "Joanne");
        rView.getItems().addAll("Seuss", "Rowling", "King", "Shakespeare");

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(lView, pane, rView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        connectCells(lCellFactory, "Bill", rCellFactory, "Shakespeare", linePane);
        connectCells(lCellFactory, "Doctor", rCellFactory, "Seuss", linePane);
        connectCells(lCellFactory, "Steve", rCellFactory, "King", linePane);
        connectCells(lCellFactory, "Joanne", rCellFactory, "Rowling", linePane);
    }

    // Looks up the ListCell<> for each String and creates a Line
    // with the coordinates from each Cell. The calculation is very 
    // contrived because I know that all the components have the same 
    // x-coordinate. You'll need more complicated calculations if your
    // containers are not aligned this way.
    private void connectCells(CustomCellFactory lCellFactory, String lVal,
            CustomCellFactory rCellFactory, String rVal, Pane linePane) {

        List<ListCell<String>> lList = lCellFactory.getAllCells();
        ListCell<String> lCell = null;

        for (ListCell<String> lc : lList) {
            if (lc.getItem() != null && lc.getItem().equals(lVal)) {
                lCell = lc;
                break;
            }
        }

        List<ListCell<String>> rList = rCellFactory.getAllCells();
        ListCell<String> rCell = null;

        for (ListCell<String> rc : rList) {
            if (rc.getItem() != null && rc.getItem().equals(rVal)) {
                rCell = rc;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (lCell != null && rCell != null) {
            double startY = lCell.getLayoutY() +
                    (lCell.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2);
            double endY = rCell.getLayoutY() +
                    (rCell.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2);

            Line line = new Line(0, startY, 
                    linePane.getBoundsInParent().getWidth(), endY);
            line.setStrokeWidth(2);
            line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            linePane.getChildren().add(line);
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the op wants to determine the position of a cell without having to select it...

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky layout. I updated my example accordingly. I'm not familiar with Piccolo2D, so I don't know how much easier JavaFX will make it (if at all).