# JavaFX ListView: retrieve position of a row

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Does the JavaFX ListView have a property which returns which rows are currently shown in its view area?  Or is there a way to assign an EventHandler to a specific row that sends the event when its position in the list changes (due to new objects being added to the List or objects being removed from the list)?

In essence I need to know the x,y coordinates of a selected row to know if a selected row is off the current view area.  Because if that happens I need to call the ListView.scrollTo() method to give focus back to the selected row.  And this situation can occur if a user selects a row then the program adds more objects to the list which would push any existing objects, including the selected one, off the view area.

I tried adding a ListChangeListener to the observable list below, but it seems like I can't apply that to a specific row.  And that ListChangeListener appears to only indicate if a row was "added/removed/updated/replaced/permutated" etc.  That event handler/listener doesn't seem to give an x,y coordinate of the specific row, nor does it give some sort of boolean indication that the row is within the current view area of the ListView object.

```
observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>()
{
   @override
   public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Object> c)
       {
           while(c.next())
           {
             if(c.wasAdded())
             {
             }
             else if(c.wasRemoved())
             {
             }
             .....
           }
       }
    }
```

I also see that getting the `ListViews.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getObject().getLayoutX() or LayoutY()` 
for some reason always returns 0,0 for x-y coordinates.

The only thing that appears to give me valid x-y coordinates is when I click on a row and the OnMouseClickEvent(MouseEvent event) callback is initiated. The event returns the x,y position of where its clicked.  But unfortunately that doesn't give me the x-y position of a selected row if the ListView dynamically adds new objects to the top of the list and the position of the selected row is changed.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no API for what you're looking for. Tomas Mikula's third party library [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) offers some functionality similar to what you're looking for (I think).

Comment: Note that in much of your question, you confuse the data with the view of the data. For example: "I tried adding a `ListChangeListener` to the `ObservableList`... that event handler doesn't seem to give an x,y coordinate of the specific row". The point is that items in your list don't have coordinates (*cells* have coordinates, not items): the item may not even have any corresponding cell or any UI at all. See the [`Cell` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html). None of this prevents a `getVisibleRowIndices()` API; however it just doesn't exist

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965871/how-to-get-position-of-an-item-in-listview-in-javafx

Answer (score 3):

There is, to my knowledge, no API to do this. Adding this functionality is a bit tricky, because of the cell reuse mechanism (described in the [`Cell` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html)).

You need to use a cell factory on the list view that keeps track of which items in the list have active cells, and what the bounds of those cells are (since it is possible during scrolling that an item may still have a cell, but that cell may be scrolled completely out of view). You can do this with an `ObservableMap` that maps items to the bounds of their cells. You need to update the map when the cell is reused, removing the old item and adding a map entry for the new item, and also update the map if the bounds of the cell change or if the cell moves within the scene.

Here's an example of doing this. I put the core functionality into a custom cell factory and exposed the observable map. As an example, I created a `ListView<Integer>` with 100 items, and to demo the functionality created a second list view whose contents are the items which have cells that are completely displayed. The second list view displays both those items and their bounds (translated to coordinates in the list view containing the cells).

In theory this is pretty performance intensive, as it updates the second list view by observing a lot of data; this is alleviated somewhat by the fact that it only does that for each cell (not each item). On my system it seems to run fine, and because performance is a function only of the number of cells it should scale fine to large lists.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TrackCellsInListView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // main list view:
        ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(i);
        }

        // create a cell factory that tracks items which have cells and the bounds of their cells:
        TrackingListCellFactory<Integer> cellFactory = new TrackingListCellFactory<>(i -> "Item "+i);
        listView.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        // map from items with cells to bounds of the cells (in scene coordinates):
        ObservableMap<Integer, Bounds> boundsByItem = cellFactory.getBoundsByItem();

        // list view which will display which items have cells that are completely displayed
        // (i.e. whose bounds are completely contained in the list view bounds):

        ListView<Integer> visibleCells = new ListView<>();

        // cell factory for second list cell displays item and its bounds (translated to
        // list view coordinates):
        visibleCells.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<Integer> cell = new ListCell<>();
            cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding( 
                () -> {
                    if (cell.getItem()==null) {
                        return null ;
                    }
                    Bounds b = boundsByItem.get(cell.getItem());
                    if (b == null) {
                        return null ;
                    }
                    Bounds bounds = listView.sceneToLocal(b);
                    return String.format("%d: [%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f]", cell.getItem(), 
                            bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMaxY());
                }, cell.itemProperty(), boundsByItem));
            return cell ;
        });

        // keep list of items in second list view up to date by observing map:
        boundsByItem.addListener((Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Bounds> c) -> {
            Bounds listBounds = listView.localToScene(listView.getBoundsInLocal());
            visibleCells.getItems().setAll(
                    boundsByItem.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(s -> listBounds.contains(boundsByItem.get(s)))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            System.out.println();
        });

        // usual UI setup:
        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(5, listView, visibleCells));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class TrackingListCellFactory<T> implements Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> {

        // function for mapping item to text to display:
        private Function<T,String> textFunction ;

        // map items which have cells to bounds of those cell in scene coordinates:
        private ObservableMap<T, Bounds> boundsByItem = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

        TrackingListCellFactory(Function<T,String> textFunction) {
            this.textFunction = textFunction ;
        }

        // default text function just calls toString():
        TrackingListCellFactory() {
            this(T::toString);
        }

        public ObservableMap<T, Bounds> getBoundsByItem() {
            return boundsByItem ;
        }


        @Override
        public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> param) {

            //create cell that displays text according to textFunction:
            ListCell<T> cell = new ListCell<T>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(item == null ? null : textFunction.apply(item));
                }
            };

            // add and remove from map when cell is reused for different item:
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    boundsByItem.remove(oldItem);
                }
                if (newItem != null) {
                    boundsByItem.put(newItem, cell.localToScene(cell.getBoundsInLocal()));
                }
            });

            // update map when bounds of item change
            ChangeListener<Object> boundsChangeHandler = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                T item = cell.getItem() ;
                if (item != null) {
                    boundsByItem.put(item, cell.localToScene(cell.getBoundsInLocal()));
                }
            };

            // must update either if cell changes bounds, or if cell moves within scene (e.g.by scrolling):
            cell.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(boundsChangeHandler);
            cell.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(boundsChangeHandler);

            return cell;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```